# Confusion regarding reaction pathway followed in reaction with lucas reagent

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Recently I came across a problem involving Lucas reagent. It asks what is the major product when 2-methylbutanol is treated by HCl in presence of anhydrous ZnCl2? The answer says major product is 2-chloro-2-methylbutane. The reason it gives is 1,2 hydride shift. But my question is whether Sn1 reaction will even occur? I knew primary alcohols always follow Sn2 mechanism.Hence no rearrangement would take place.Can someone clarify what's happening?
Thank you

Comment: Lucas reagent always gives SN1. It's designed in a way to give SN1, that's the only reason it can differentiate between primary, secondary and tertiary alcohols.

Comment: @Nisarg Bhavsar But my book says and I have verified it on internet that primary alcohols do follow Sn2 mechanism

Comment: That is overdone by the highly acidic conditions made by adding HCl. Even ZnCl2 acts as a Lewis acid and thus increases the chances of SN1 reaction. Furthermore the Lewis acid nature of ZnCl2 also decreases the nucleophilicity of chloride ions thus even curbing the SN2 pathway. Lucas reagent is designed to follow SN1 pathway and it efficiency does so.